# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\Big\{\int_{y^2}^{\pi}\frac{y\sin x}{x} dx\Big\}dy$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

I want to evaluate the following problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks to you in advance. 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left\{\int_{y^2}^{\pi}\frac{y\sin x}{x} dx\right\}dy$$

Comment: Are you sure that you integrate in $y$ on $[0,\pi]$? Not on $[0,\sqrt{\pi}]$?

Comment: @ user539887: I want to integrate on the said interval.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is a singularity about $x=0$, one can work with
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1/N}^{\pi}\int_{y^{2}}^{\pi}\dfrac{y\sin x}{x}dxdy&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1/N^{2}}^{\pi}\int_{1/N}^{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{y\sin x}{x}dydx.
\end{align*}

As pointed by @user539887, there is another term, as written in the comment box.

Comment: Since the OP integrates in $y$ on $[0,\pi]$, the term $$-\int\limits_{\pi}^{\pi^2}\int\limits_{\sqrt{x}}^{\pi} \frac{y \sin{x}}{x} \, dy \, dx = \int\limits_{\pi}^{\pi^2}\int\limits_{\pi}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{y \sin{x}}{x} \, dy \, dx$$ is missing.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out.

Comment: Then I will guess that OP made some typo.

Comment: I think so.  Let's wait for their answer.

Comment: @  user284331: I didn't make any typo. That is exactly the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward using the Taylor series,

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos(\pi^2)+\pi^2 \operatorname{Si}(\pi)-\pi^2\operatorname{Si}(\pi^2)\right),$$
where $\operatorname{Si}$ is the Sine integral.

**Info about Sine integral**: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I make use of the Sine integral to arrive at my answer?

Comment: @Mike Try to finish it alone, it's very easy. Use the information provided in my post.

Comment: @ Waiting: Thanks, I'll do that!